# get value from xml node by search in java

Tags: java, xml

I have need to know whether my logic is correct or not because I am new to play with XML node.
Here is my code.
JAVA

```
        try{
        File inputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\luenwong\\Desktop\\decoded.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner( new File("C:\\Users\\luenwong\\Desktop\\decoded.txt"));
        String text = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next();
        scanner.close();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document docum = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
        docum.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        NodeList nList = docum.getElementsByTagName("row");
        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        for(int temp=0; temp<nList.getLength();temp++){
            Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
            System.out.println("\n Current Element :" + nNode.getNodeName());
            if(nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                String here = eElement.getElementsByTagName("col").item(1).getTextContent();
                    if(here.indexOf("AB02") == 0)
                    {
//                    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes());
//                    Document doc = PositionalXMLReader.readXML(is);
//                    Node test = doc.getElementsByTagName("col").item(0);
//                    System.out.println("Student roll no : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("col").item(0).getTextContent());
//                    System.out.println("Line number: " + test.getUserData("lineNumber"));
                    }
                }
            }
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mapping-table>
<col-def name="Location Description" type="nocase"/>
<col-def name="Centre Code" type="nocase"/>
<col-def name="Location Code" type="nocase"/>
<col-def name="Status" type="nocase"/>
<row>
    <col>TAMAN TUN DR ISMAIL</col>
    <col>AB02</col>
    <col>CSTDI</col>
    <col>active</col>
</row>
<row>
    <col>KUALA LUMPUR CITY CENTRE (KLCC)</col>
    <col>AA02</col>
    <col>I-CTRKLCC</col>
    <col>active</col>
</row>
</mapping-table>
```

What I am trying to do is I wish to type "AA02" and I am able to get the result as "KUALA LUMPUR CITY CENTRE (KLCC)".
My logic is that, I will be looking for the line number, and then I use the line number to -1 in order to get the result. But I do not know that is it able to find xml node by using the line number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an `XPath` instead, your code will be then much simpler to read and to maintain

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document docum = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);

XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
String codeToFind = "AA02";
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(
    String.format("/mapping-table/row[col='%s']/col[1]", codeToFind)
);
Node node = (Node) expr.evaluate(docum, XPathConstants.NODE);
System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
```

**Output:**

```
KUALA LUMPUR CITY CENTRE (KLCC)
```

The `XPath` used here is `/mapping-table/row[col='my code here']/col[1]` meaning that we are looking for the first child `col` of the element `row` which has a child `col` whose text content is the code to find.

**NB:** The code above assumes that we have only one match, if you expect more than one match, then instead of getting a `Node` you need to get a `NodeList` using the next code:

```
NodeList nl = (NodeList) expr.evaluate(docum, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
    Node node = nl.item(i);
    System.out.println(node.getTextContent());
}
```

Comment: it really works. may I have more information about xPath? because I do not really understand about this line of code. String.format("/mapping-table/row[col='%s']/col[1]", code). Maybe could you explain to me? thank you. I will mark your answer as the best answer.

Comment: I explained at the end of the answer (before the NB), it is not clear enough?

Comment: so mean that. I have to get into the exact row and always get the first column?

Comment: yes, at least it is how I understood your need, it is not what you expected?

Comment: yes. this is what i need. You are my god to me. may I ask you one more question? what does this mean? row[col='%s']? sorry for asking so much because I am trying to understand instead of copy and paste so I am able to do some modification if needed.

Comment: it is only a String format, it is simply a generic way to build `/mapping-table/row[col='my code here']/col[1]`

Comment: thanks @Nicolas Filotto. I feel like I have gained a lot of knowledge from you. really appreciated.

Comment: Good News, I'm happy to help

Comment: hi @Nicolas Filotto feel like wanna know the answer in all of the sudden. is it possible to find the content if all my <col> in different name like <col1><col2><col3>?

Comment: of course it would be even better as relying on an index is quite risky/error prone, the `XPath` would then be `/mapping-table/row[col2='%s']/col1`

Comment: if it is like that, mean that I can only use col2 as my keyword right? and if I want col3 as my keyword then I have to use /mapping-table/row[col3='%s']/col1 ?

Comment: alright thank you. mean that I can only rely on one keyword.